# Css menu hover displays a box

Tags: css

So I wanted to make a css navigation bar where once the users hovers over it, it shows a box with contect.
[image: Image 1] Before hover.
[image: Image 1] After hover.
Is this possible I have been trying but failing. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, completely possible with pure CSS. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried making a ul with a li and the li:hover displays the ul in between the original li

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/X367v/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Check out this Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/X367v/2/)**

Yes this can be achieved by putting you hover box in to the li element and then giving the parent element position relative and child one absolute.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li class="box">Categories
        <div class="arrow_box">Box with Content</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 25px 10px;
}
ul li.box {
    position: relative;
}
.arrow_box { background: #88b7d5; border: 4px solid #c2e1f5; } .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before { bottom: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; } .arrow_box:after { border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); border-bottom-color: #88b7d5; border-width: 30px; left: 50%; margin-left: -30px; } .arrow_box:before { border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5; border-width: 36px; left: 50%; margin-left: -36px; }
.arrow_box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 68px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    left: -50px;
}
ul li.box:hover .arrow_box {
    display: block;

}
```

Use this to create css arrow --> http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: This is very close but once you hover over the categories and move the cursor down over the box it disappears. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes check the updated fiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/X367v/2/ .. actually you just need to play with the padding of li elements and it can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can try like this. Assuming the navigation menu have an a tag:

```
div {
    display: none;
}
a:hover ~ div:nth-child(n) {
    display: block;
    background-color: RED;
    height: 250px;
    width: 960px;
}
```

replace the n with the order of yor div. For example if you put a div next to the a tag then the value for n will be 2.

UPDATE:

you can also try using the classname or id of the div:

```
a:hover ~ .classname {
    display: block;
    background-color: RED;
    height: 250px;
    width: 960px;
}
```